# Xcode 5.0.1 - Mavericks - Where is the installation folder?

Tags: xcode5, osx-mavericks

I'm looking for the Xcode 5.0.1 download so I can copy it from one computer to another without downloading it again, on OS X Mavericks. Does anyone have any idea where I could find it?

Regards,
Paul

EDIT: My friend downloaded 5.0.1 and I wish to copy the download from his computer to mine, I asked him if he had an /Applications/Install XCode.app, but he says he doesn't have it. So my question is where else could it be? If anyone knows I would be grateful.

Comment: Inside Application Folder ? Or just download it from iTunes in the other computer ? I don't really understand what do you want

Comment: `/Applications/Xcode.app`, just like every other version.

Comment: Can the Xcode.app be copied from one computer to another and be installed and run? I thought I might need to copy a .dmg file?

Comment: you can copy Xcode.app to another computer. dmg is like zip file. just used to pack and compress files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously an installer was downloaded which installed Xcode in /Developers/XCode. Afaik, the installer is gone and XCode now resides in /Applications/Xcode.app.

Comment: Thanks, I just copied the Xcode.app file from one computer to another and it worked. I was confused only because I thought I would need to copy the download and do a new install, but copying the Xcode.app file just works like you said.